# Short: What is the name of the eclipse plugin that tracks a Java program like LWJGL?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, lwjgl

I know there is this plugin which you can put in eclipse that tells you which command is being used the most or which method or something and how many times its called and stuff... it might not be a plugin.. Does anyone know the name of this thing-ma-bob?

I saw some guy use it to track LWJGL but i cant find it anymore..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about a "profiler", you can do that using Eclipse via the Eclipse Test & Performance Tools Platform (see http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/). There are various other (commercials) tools for doing this out there and the VisualVM tool that comes with the JDK can also do CPU & memory profiling these days.

Comment: I guess that is it but is there just a simple plugin that does that because I cant get this one to work...

Comment: I found it! It was VisualVM! Thanks!